# Is there a bijection from the real numbers cross the naturals to the reals?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijection from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1. Prove that there is a bijection $f$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,1)$.

STEP 2. Divide $\mathbb{R}$ into countable pieces of copies of $[0,1)$.